# Google Webmaster Tools Index Status is 0 but sitemap URL shows indexed

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I've added my site to Google Webmaster Tools.
The site was submitted a few weeks ago. The index status shows 0 but it shows 6 URLs have been indexed in the sitemaps section.
If I search in Google I can see that the site is indexed and several pages appear:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Awww.medexpress.co.uk&oq=site%3Awww.medexpress.co.uk&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

My question is why is the index status 0 when the sitemap section shows several indexed pages and also the pages appear in the search engine.

Comment: Are you looking for reliable information regarding the number of indexed pages?

Comment: > The URLs you have indexed have both the HTTPS and HTTP protocol in
> them along with www. These would be reported separately in Webmaster
> Tools, so if your verified site in Webmaster Tools is HTTP plus www,
> the sitemap count wont report on the HTTPS links and vice-versa.
> > As you seem to be redirecting to HTTPS, ensure you have an HTTPS
> version verified and a sitemap uploaded with HTTPS URLs and you will
> likely get more accurate data. Are you creating 2 sitemaps -one for http:// and one for https:// prortocol (2 properties are created separately in webmaster and site is using redir

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sadly Google's Webmaster Tools doesn't use REALTIME DATA and is updated in intervals from a few days and sometimes I've seen some data missing for up to 2 weeks. So there's nothing to be worried about, your URLS are indexed as Google updates the rankings more often they do Webmaster Tools.

You will also find similar problems with Traffic, and Keyword Data these tend to behind from 3 days and again I've seen the data not be updated for 2 weeks a time.

Comment: as an aside do you think the link to my website on my above post will contribute positively to my SEO?

Comment: @DD. No, the link in your post will not contribute +/- to SEO since it contains a `rel="nofollow"` attr. As to the difference between the "Index Status" (Total indexed) and "Sitemap Indexed" figures (since they are both reported by GWT)... as bybe says, real time data is not used and these two figures report on different things. Whilst it _might_ be correct (in your case) to show a "Total indexed" figure that matches the number indexed from the Sitemap, this is not necessarily the case, so to do so would be incorrect. The "Total indexed" figure therefore needs to be calculated independently.

Answer (score 7):

The URLs you have indexed have both the HTTPS and HTTP protocol in them along with `www`. These would be reported separately in Webmaster Tools, so if your verified site in Webmaster Tools is HTTP plus `www`, the sitemap count wont report on the HTTPS links and vice-versa.

As you seem to be redirecting to HTTPS, ensure you have an HTTPS version verified and a sitemap uploaded with HTTPS URLs and you will likely get more accurate data.

See the bottom of [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) for more information.